# Problems Displaying Profile Picture in Flash swf

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook, api

I followed this tutorial [Loading Facebook Profile Picture Into Flash SWF Using Graph API](http://www.permadi.com/blog/2010/12/loading-facebook-profile-picture-into-flash-swf-using-open-graph-api/) to get the users profile picture to show in my flash game, but I'm having some issues.

```
import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;
import com.facebook.graph.data.FacebookSession;
import com.facebook.graph.net.FacebookRequest;

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;

//place your APP ID here
const APP_ID:String = "app_id";

//Initialize facebbok library
Facebook.init(APP_ID, HandleLogin);

function HandleLogin(response:Object, fail:Object):void
{
    if(Facebook.getSession().accessToken)
    {
        LoadMyInfo();
        LoadMyPicture();
    }
}

function LoadMyInfo():void
{
    Facebook.api("/me", MyInfoLoaded);
}

function MyInfoLoaded(response:Object, fail:Object):void
{
    nameTextField.text = response.name;
}

function LoadMyPicture():void
{
    debug.text = "Entered loadMyPicture() function ";

    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, MyPictureLoaded, false, 0, true);

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("facebookProxy.php");
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

    variables.path = Facebook.getImageUrl(String(Facebook.getSession().uid), 'large');

    debug.appendText(" \nvariables.path: " + String(variables.path));

    request.data = variables;

    debug.appendText(" \nrequest.data: " + String(request.data))

    loader.load(request);

    debug.appendText(" \n" + String(loader.load(request)));
}

function MyPictureLoaded(event:Event):void 
{
    debug.appendText(" \nEntering MyPictureLoaded");

    var loader:Loader = event.target.loader;
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, MyPictureLoaded);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, MyPictureLoadError);        
    var bitmap = Bitmap(loader.content);
    bitmap.smoothing = true;

    //Note: picturePlaceholder is just a blank movie clip on the Stage
    bitmap.x = picturePlaceHolder.x;
    bitmap.y = picturePlaceHolder.y;
    bitmap.width = picturePlaceHolder.width;
    bitmap.height = picturePlaceHolder.height;
    picturePlaceHolder.addChild(bitmap);

    debug.appendText(" \nBitmap is null: " + String(bitmap == null) +
                     " \nBitmap X: " + String(bitmap.x) + " Bitmap Y: " + String(bitmap.y) +
                     " \nBitmap width: " + String(bitmap.width) +
                     " \nBitmap height: " + String(bitmap.height))
}

function MyPictureLoadError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    debug.appendText("Loading Error");
}
```

This is what my code looks like after following the tutorials on the link above.  With the debug I noticed that the function **MyPictureLoaded** is never called.

They never specified where I would call the function **LoadMyPicture**.  I assumed it would go together with **LoadMyInfo** so I placed it there.  They have a working example but no source code, so I'm hope someone here would shed some light on this.

**EDIT 1**

[Here](http://tinypic.com/r/2dqpkpy/7) is what it looks like when I put it up on facebook.  The last line **debug.appendText(" \n" + String(loader.load(request)));** is outputting undefined.  I also made a change in the **variables.path = Facebook.getImageUrl(String(Facebook.getSession().uid), 'large');** I added *(String(), 'large')* because in the docs it saying to pass strings into there.  *Edit: I realized adding String() is pointless.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("facebookProxy.php");
```

Did you do the part of the tutorial that writes a server-side PHP proxy loader on your server?

If you don't have a file named facebookProxy.php on your server where you run this it won't work (the code is requesting "./facebookProxy.php" which probably doesn't exist). If you want to run this in the debugger on your local machine, you will need to make that file in the same directory as your swf and make sure you have apache/php running on your localhost.

If that's too much work for you, I would suggest following some of the examples from the API' project page: http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/downloads/detail?name=GraphAPI_Examples_1_6.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: I do have the facebookProxy.php in the save folder as my swf file is on my server.  Which example would help me best in that zip file?

Comment: The FlashWebExample folder is probably closest to what you're doing.

Comment: Hmm seems the problem I'm having is getting this **loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, MyPictureLoaded, false, 0, true);** to execute.  I have a debug to display when the function MyPictureLoaded runs but the debug never shows up.  So I might have to start a new question.

Comment: Ok then I suggest you add some more listeners to your loader to better debug what's happening to your connection:

loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
loader.addEventListener(Event.INIT, initHandler);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
loader.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
loader.addEventListener(Event.UNLOAD, unLoadHandler);

Comment: In each function you should just output the event you get to get some more information about what's going on. Make sure you add these listeners before you call loader.load().

Comment: I had to added .contentLoaderInfo before the addEventListener.  What happened was it went into httpStatusHandler, openHandler, ioErrorHandler.  What does this mean?

Comment: So if it's going into the ioErrorHandler then clearly there's an error with the data I'm passing into the loader.  The debugs I have set show that it's urls I'm passing into loader.load() but it's still getting an error when loading.  How would I debug this?